# Match character and any whitespaces around it

Tags: regex

I have a file containing informations in the following format :
`Fred,Frank , Marcel Godwin , Marion,Ryan`

I need the match commas and any whitespace around them, but not any comma inside brackets.

My problem is that with my current regex  `[\s,]+` the whitespaces between words are matched. So in this example the whitespace between **Marcel** and **Godwin**.

I thought about using something like `\s,\s*` but it wouldn't match parts when there is no whitespace around the comma, like between **Fred** and **Frank**

Surely, it's a simple fix but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You have to use lookahead or lookbehind. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I know the concept but I can't say I know how to use them in that context. These are things like this `\s(?=,)` right ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, doesn't `\s*,\s*` solve your problem?

Comment: @ValentinBriand There we go, I knew it had to be something minute. This seems to be the right answer. Thank you !

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *"but not any comma inside brackets"*? Because the above suggestion would not cater for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will match the commas including the whitespace before and afterwards like you explained in your question.

```
\s*(?=\,)\,(?<=\,)\s*
```

This is a positive looahead: `(?=\,)`, it means it matches any whitespace if there is a comma afterwards.

This is a positive lookbehind: `(?<=\,)`, it means it matches any whitespace if there is a comma rigth before.

Try it out yourself. You can use this [page](https://regex101.com/) to check the output in your browser.